# What can be problem in this line with PDO?

Tags: php, pdo, rowcount

I'm just learning from zero everything.

I try to change my mysqli to pdo and in this function when I change all, the website gives a blank page.

it is about `return $result->rowCount();>= 1 ? $user['user_id'] : false;`I presume but what is the mistake here?

```
function loggedInUserId(){
    if(isLoggedIn()){
        $result = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" . $_SESSION['username'] ."'");
        $result->execute();
        confirmQuery($result);
        $user = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
        return $result->rowCount();>= 1 ? $user['user_id'] : false;
    }
    return false;

}
```

previous code:

```
function loggedInUserId(){
    if(isLoggedIn()){
        $result = query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" . $_SESSION['username'] ."'");
        confirmQuery($result);
        $user = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        return mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1 ? $user['user_id'] : false;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: this line just makes no sense. it's invalid syntax. besides, your query is a classical case of sql injection. Why bother with pdo if you don't use prepared statement properly?

Comment: with PDO, you don't need fetch and rowCount. just use fetchColumn() and return its result right away